# ResultSet exception - before start of result set

Tags: java, jdbc

I'm having trouble getting data from a [`ResultSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.sql/java/sql/ResultSet.html) object. Here is my code:

```
    String sql = "SELECT type FROM node WHERE nid = ?";
    PreparedStatement prep = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
    int meetNID = Integer.parseInt(node.get(BoutField.field_meet_nid));
    prep.setInt(1, meetNID);

    ResultSet result = prep.executeQuery();
    result.beforeFirst();
    String foundType = result.getString(1);

    if (! foundType.equals("meet")) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(String.format("Node %d must be of type 'meet', but was %s", meetNID, foundType));
    }
```

The error trace:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: Before start of result set
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1072)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:986)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:981)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:926)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.checkRowPos(ResultSetImpl.java:841)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.getStringInternal(ResultSetImpl.java:5656)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.getString(ResultSetImpl.java:5576)
    at nth.cumf3.nodeImport.Validator.validate(Validator.java:43)
    at nth.cumf3.nodeImport.Main.main(Main.java:38)
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 195, accepted):

Basically you are positioning the cursor before the first row and then requesting data. You need to move the cursor to the first row.

```
 result.next();
 String foundType = result.getString(1);
```

It is common to do this in an if statement or loop.

```
if(result.next()){
   foundType = result.getString(1);
}
```

Comment: Would it be safe to use result.next() or result.first() when executing a simple COUNT query because it should never be null and will only ever be 1 result.

Comment: Maybe use `result.first()` for this scenario.

Comment: Turns out first returns a Boolean not the first result as I originally thought. Seems I couldn’t do this on 1 line like I was trying to do and had to use above logic to execute the query, then next, then getInt(1). Oh well.

Answer (score 12):

Every answer uses [`.next()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.sql/java/sql/ResultSet.html#next()) or uses [`.beforeFirst()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.sql/java/sql/ResultSet.html#beforeFirst()) and then `.next()`. But why not this:

```
result.first();
```

So You just set the pointer to the first record and go from there. It's available since java 1.2 and I just wanted to mention this for anyone whose `ResultSet` exists of one specific record.

Comment: Use of `first()` requires a scrollable result set. The API requires that an exception is thrown if the result set is `TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY`.

Comment: Just do preparedStatement(sql, ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);

Answer (score 11):

You have to do a result.next() before you can access the result.  It's a very common idiom to do

```
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery();
while (rs.next())
{
   int foo = rs.getInt(1);
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You have to call `next()` before you can start reading values from the first row. `beforeFirst` puts the cursor *before* the first row, so there's no data to read.

Answer (score 2):

It's better if you create a class that has all the query methods, inclusively, in a different package, so instead of typing all the process in every class, you just call the method from that class.

Answer (score 1):

You need to move the pointer to the first row, before asking for data:

```
result.beforeFirst();
result.next();
String foundType = result.getString(1);
```

Answer (score 0):

The error you're encountering, "Before start of result set," occurs because you're trying to retrieve data from the result set before moving the cursor to the first row of the result set. The 'beforeFirst()' method moves the cursor before the first row, and then you're immediately trying to retrieve data using result.getString(1), which is causing the exception.