# Java: MySQL query. Get generated ID

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I have a table that contains a column called 'id' that is an INT that auto increments and is set to be the primary key.

I need to get the value of the generated ID after the query is run. I have the following:

```
String sql = "INSERT...";
Statement statement = sqlConnection.createStatement();
    int result = statement.executeUpdate(sql, Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
    this.id = statement.getGeneratedKeys().getInt("id");
```

I get the following exception on the last line of code:

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: java.sql.SQLException: Column 'id' not found.
    com.joelj.music.rest.NewUser.doPost(NewUser.java:44)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:754)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)
    com.joelj.music.rest.filters.Prefilter.doFilter(Prefilter.java:44)
```

If I change it to `statement.getGeneratedKeys().getInt(0);` I get the following:

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: java.sql.SQLException: Before start of result set
    com.joelj.music.rest.NewUser.doPost(NewUser.java:44)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:754)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)
    com.joelj.music.rest.filters.Prefilter.doFilter(Prefilter.java:44)
```

I've gone through the other methods and have tried this and that. I have looked at example code found on the internet. I just can't see what I'm doing wrong.

*Note: The query is run in both of the solutions I've included. So the connection works fine. It's getting back the value of the ID that isn't working.*

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using statement.getGeneratedKeys().getInt(1)? The Result set is one based.

Comment: Ahh, you have a second problem, check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2120255/java-resultset-exception-before-start-of-result-set

Comment: had to call `.next()` on the result set before calling `.getInt(1)`. Awesome. Thanks Michael