# SQLException : Before start of result set

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, resultset, sqlexception

```
   ResultSet rs;
   rs = this.orderedProduct.select(" sum(unitstoproduce) "," soNo = "+ soNo);

   int sum = Integer.parseInt(rs.getString(1));
```

When i try to execute the above query inside the java class i'm getting an **exception** as below. 
Here the orderedProduct(orderedZnAlProduct) is the table

```
   SELECT  sum(unitstoproduce)  FROM orderedZnAlProduct WHERE  soNo = '15005'

   java.sql.SQLException: Before start of result set
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ResultSet exception - before start of result set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2120255/resultset-exception-before-start-of-result-set)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I don't see where your query is executed (like statement.executeQuery()) but, this kind of errors generally happens when your cursor is not well positioned. You need to call something like`rs.next()` or `rs.first()` to move your cursor and then to get the result.

Answer (score 1):

Even I encountered the same problem when I tried to execute

```
select count(*) TABLE_NAME
```

But I never encountered the error in any other scenarios when retrieving the values, So I assumed for the queries which have only one row we need to explicitly mention `rs.first()` and it 'll work like a charm.

Comment: Dafuuu... SQL/JDBC can truly be a pain sometimes >< just spent two hours of debugging til finding this thread...