# An exception occurred processing JSP page

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, oop, jdbc

I am attempting to return the count of mysql rows. I get the following error when I run the .jsp file:

> org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing
>   JSP page /index.jsp at line 54

Which is this line of code:

```
// count posts in category 1
catCount = conn.countCategoryPosts(1);
```

I know the database connection is setup fine. 
This is the `countCategoryPosts` method.

```
public int countCategoryPosts(int ncatID) throws Exception{
    int catID = ncatID;
    try{
        sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM crm_posts WHERE cat_id = ?";
        prep = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
        prep.setInt(1, catID);
        rs = prep.executeQuery();
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return rs.getInt(1);
}
```

What is causing the error?

EDIT: As requested the full stacktrace:

```
type Exception report

message An exception occurred processing JSP page /index.jsp at line 54

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing JSP page /index.jsp at line 54

51:                         id = Integer.parseInt(catAttributes[1]);
52:                         
53:                         // count posts in this category
54:                         catCount = conn.countCategoryPosts(1);
55:                         
56:                         // get posts in this category
57:                         postList = conn.getCategoryPosts(id);


Stacktrace:
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:568)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:455)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.RuleChain.handleRewrite(RuleChain.java:176)
    org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.RuleChain.doRules(RuleChain.java:145)
    org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriter.processRequest(UrlRewriter.java:92)
    org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriteFilter.doFilter(UrlRewriteFilter.java:394)
root cause

javax.servlet.ServletException: java.sql.SQLException: Before start of result set
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.doHandlePageException(PageContextImpl.java:916)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.handlePageException(PageContextImpl.java:845)
    org.apache.jsp.index_jsp._jspService(index_jsp.java:208)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.RuleChain.handleRewrite(RuleChain.java:176)
    org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.RuleChain.doRules(RuleChain.java:145)
    org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriter.processRequest(UrlRewriter.java:92)
    org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriteFilter.doFilter(UrlRewriteFilter.java:394)
root cause

java.sql.SQLException: Before start of result set
    com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1084)
    com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:987)
    com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:973)
    com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:918)
    com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.checkRowPos(ResultSetImpl.java:850)
    com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.getInt(ResultSetImpl.java:2705)
    com.servlet.explore.dbCon.countCategoryPosts(dbCon.java:103)
    org.apache.jsp.index_jsp._jspService(index_jsp.java:145)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.RuleChain.handleRewrite(RuleChain.java:176)
    org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.RuleChain.doRules(RuleChain.java:145)
    org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriter.processRequest(UrlRewriter.java:92)
    org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriteFilter.doFilter(UrlRewriteFilter.java:394)
```

Comment: Show full stacktrace please.

Comment: okay I added it to the question.

Comment: Why do you use scriptlets?

Comment: Please post the relevant *scriptlet* you use in your JSP.

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQLException : Before start of result set](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3715839/sqlexception-before-start-of-result-set)

Comment: could someone explain why my question might be down voted? So I know for future questions.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza what is your alternative to scriplets please, I am new to Java Web dev. Previously PHP.

Comment: Refer to [How to avoid Java Code in JSP-Files?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3177733/1065197)

Comment: You do not respect MVC pattern when calling storage from the JSP. You'd better follow MVC pattern and add layers which will manage the data ascent to the view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not call

```
rs.getInt(1)
```

if you did not move your cursor with

```
rs.next() // for example
```

This should work:

```
public int countCategoryPosts(int ncatID) throws Exception{
    int catID = ncatID;
    int result = 0;
    try{
        sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM crm_posts WHERE cat_id = ?";
        prep = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
        prep.setInt(1, catID);
        rs = prep.executeQuery();
        if (rs.next()) {
           result = rs.getInt(1);
        }
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Is there a more approriate way of doing this, given that only one row will be returned if it is a count?

Comment: You can use `rs.first()` instead of `rs.next()`.