# Exception in MySQL

Tags: java

I have written a code in Java which has to populate a dot file. I am getting the error and I cant figure out why. All of the paths have been set.

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");                     
Connection connects = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/userlogin", "root","12345");
Statement stm = connects.createStatement();
ResultSet rs=stm.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM authors_4 WHERE self_authors='"+getTxt+"'");

                         int l=0;
                         /*if(rsx.next())
                         {
                             div = Double.parseDouble(rsx.getString("divs"));


                         }*/


                       do
                         {
                             if(l==0)
                             {

                                 diva = Integer.parseInt(rs.getString("tot_pub"));

                                 //fout.write("a [label=" + "\"" + rsx.getString(2) + "\\n" + rsx.getString(4) + "\"" + "color=blue,fontsize=24,fontcolor=red,style=filled];\r\n");
                                 fout.write("\"" + rs.getString("self_authors") + "\"" + "[fixedsize=true, width="+diva+",height="+diva+", label=" + "\"" + rs.getString("self_authors") + "\\n" + rs.getString("tot_pub") + "\"" + "color=blue,fontsize=24,fontcolor=red,style=filled];\r\n");
                               l++;
                             }


                             divb = Integer.parseInt(rs.getString("tot_pub")) ;

                             fout.write("\"" + rs.getString("co_auths") + "\"" + "[fixedsize=true, width="+divb+",height="+divb+",label=" + "\"" + rs.getString("co_auths") + "\\n" + rs.getString("tot_pub") + "\"];" +"\r\n");    


                             //fout.write("a ->" + "\"" + rsx.getString(6) + "\"" + "[penwidth=" +  rsx.getString(8)  +", label =" + rsx.getString(8) +" ];" + "\r\n");
                               fout.write("\"" + rs.getString("self_authors") + "\" ->" + "\"" + rs.getString("co_auths") + "\"" + "[penwidth=" +  rs.getString("1")  +", label =" + 1 +" ];" + "\r\n");

                             //System.out.println(rsx.getString(1));

                         }while(rs.next());

                         fout.write("}");
                         fout.close();
                     }
```

The code that I have written is very long and cant be explained so I'm only posting the portion where I am getting exceptions.

The exceptions are:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Before start of result set
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1078)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:989)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:975)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:920)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.checkRowPos(ResultSetImpl.java:855)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.getStringInternal(ResultSetImpl.java:5773)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.getString(ResultSetImpl.java:5693)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.getString(ResultSetImpl.java:5733)
```

Comment: Have you already looked at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2120255/java-resultset-exception-before-start-of-result-set?rq=1 ? Since you show very little of your code I'm not sure whether it applies to your case,

Comment: You should also use parameters to stop potential SQL injection attacks.

Comment: @PM 77-1 code has been added for further clarification

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The body of a `do-while` loop executes *before* the `while` expression is evaluated.

This means that your cursor will not have advanced in the first pass of the loop. You need to use a `while` loop:

```
while(rs.next()) {
   ...
}
```

Also consider using `PreparedStatement` to protect against SQL injection attacks.

Comment: Now I get "java.sql.SQLException: After end of result set"

Comment: Sounds like you are navigating past the end of the resultset. Is the `rs.next()` in the while loop your only call to `next`? `ResultSet#next` returns a boolean which you need to check before attempting to read any values. Using it in a while loop performs this check

Answer (score 1):

The code you posted is not throwing any error, I believe. This error is returned when you try to access the result set data without moving the cursor to the first record.

```
ResultSet rs = stm.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM authors_4 WHERE self_authors='"+getTxt+"'");

// Did you use rs.next() ???
while (rs.next())
{
   // You need rs.next() before trying to access 
   // Without rs.next(), you'll see the "Before start of result set" exception
   int myInt = rs.getInt(1);   
   ...
   ...
}
```

Comment: Yes I am using rs.next() while populating the dot file right after the resultset

Comment: So, this is the answer the, Use rs.next() before using rs.getString("tot_pub")

Comment: Now I get "java.sql.SQLException: After end of result set"

Answer (score 1):

The exception is telling you that you're positioning the cursor before the first row of data and then requesting data from it. I can't be sure of this, because you haven't posted the part of the code where you request data, but that's the only context in which I've seen this exception come up. You need to call:

```
rs.next();
```

to move the cursor to the first row of data.

EDIT: As I expected, you're calling `diva = Integer.parseInt(rs.getString("tot_pub"));` before calling rs.next(); So it's trying to get a string from the line before the first line returned by the database. Simply add `rs.next();` before making that call, and your problem is solved.

Comment: More code has been added

Comment: It didnt work "java.sql.SQLException: After end of result set" now it returned this exception

Answer (score 0):

Please replace **while(rs.next())** with **while(rs.hasNext())**

and inside the **Do-While loop** the first statement as **rs.next()**.

**rs.hasNext()** will check for any existing value in ResultSet if any value is present then it will go further, otherwise it will exit the loop.

```
Note: I will suggest to use **While loop** instead of a **Do-While loop**.
```

hope this will help.