# Why this query does not work?

Tags: java, sql, database

I am writing a very very simple query. But i cannot find the error. Here is the code:

```
 con = DBConnect.connect();

 try {
    PreparedStatement query = (PreparedStatement) con.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM accounts where iban=?");
    query.setString(1, iban);

    ResultSet result = (ResultSet) query.executeQuery();
    double oldBalance;
    } catch (SQLException e) {
         System.out.println(e);
    }
```

I am sure that the name of the table is accounts, and there exists a column of type varchar called iban. I debugged and so i am sure that `query.setString(1, iban);` line sets iban correctly.

But when it comes to the line `ResultSet result = (ResultSet) query.executeQuery();`  it suddenly jumps to the last line, which consists of **"}"**. It does not even enter the catch block and so I cannot see the problem.

What is wrong here can anyone please tell me?

Thanks

**Edit:** Looks like query executes succesfully. Now after executequery line i just do:

```
double oldBalance=result.getDouble("iban");
```

And that gives me an error:

```
 java.sql.SQLException: Before start of result set
```

Can anyone tell me the problem here?

Comment: First, you don't need to cast an object to the same type as what the method returns. Your `ResultSet` and `PreparedStatement` casts are redundant. Second, have you selected a default DB in your connection. You should always be explicit and `SELECT * FROM schema.table` instead of relying on the connection-specified schema (which only works for MySQL anyway - unless it's in the public schema)

Comment: Clean and rebuild your project. Then run it again.

Comment: Your `oldBalance` variable isn't assigned. After the `executeQuery`line, it will jump to the last line since nothing else is to be done in the `try` block.

Comment: Make sure to use `result.next()` before calling `result.getDouble()` to retrieve the next (first) row.

Comment: Please use the JSF tag only if your question is about JSF or related to this technology (similar with other tags as well). As a recommendation, if your question happens to be about pure JSF (Facelets, RichFaces, PrimeFaces, OmniFaces, etc), it would be better **to not add the Java tag** because lot of people doesn't understand how JSF behaves and tend to vote the question for close (or [on hold]).

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza ok i will consider your recommendatiton from now on thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you debug your code, once you're at the `ResultSet result = (ResultSet) query.executeQuery();` line, since nothing else after it is to be done in the `try` block, if you go to the next step, it will jump to the end of the block.

So your query might actually be working fine, you just need to do something with it in the block since your `ResultSet` is assigned within the block.

Edit : Check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2120255/java-resultset-exception-before-start-of-result-set) for your other problem.

Comment: Thank you, that was driving me crazy. But there is one more little thing would you please look at the edited question again?

Comment: @iceface You should do another question instead but I added a link to answer your edit. If everything answer your questions, don't forget to accept the answer.