# JDBC Error: Before start of result set

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I have an error message in Java eclipse. I have a database in MySql and it has colomns String user_name, int id_time, int id_desk, int user_password. I want to one row's columns data  with using

public ArrayList showReservation(String user_name) throws SQLException{

```
    // array list keeps the information
    ArrayList<String> showReservation = new ArrayList<String>();
    try{

        String getReservationSql = "SELECT * FROM reservation " 
                +"WHERE user_name ='" + user_name + "';";
        rs = stmt.executeQuery(getReservationSql);

        // first element of the array list keeps user name
        showReservation.add("" + rs.getString("user_name")); 

        // second element of the array list keeps id of the desk which is selected by user
        showReservation.add("" + rs.getInt("id_time")); 

        // third element of the array list keeps id of the time interval which is selected by user
        showReservation.add("" + rs.getInt("id_desk"));  

        // forth element of the array list keeps user's password which is generated automatically in a controller class
        showReservation.add("" + rs.getInt("user_password")); 

    }catch (SQLException ex) {
        System.out.println("Error: " + ex.getMessage());
    }
    return showReservation;
}
```

but when i run this code i get an error: Before start of result set.
how can i fix this error?
thanks

Comment: check this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2120255/java-resultset-exception-before-start-of-result-set

Answer (score 2):

You never advance to the first result in the `ResultSet`.  Use [the `next()` method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#next--) to advance to the next record, which returns `false` when there are no more records.

```
rs = stmt.executeQuery(getReservationSql);
while (rs.next())
{
   // Make your calls to getString and getInt here
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [`next`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#next--) before attempting to call any of the `ResultSet` getter methods

```
rs = stmt.executeQuery(getReservationSql);
if (rs.next()) {
   ...
}
```

Aside: Consider [Using Prepared Statements](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html)