# Print ResultSet Java using MySQL

Tags: java, mysql

I have the next code:

```
ResultSet rs;
Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
rs = statement.executeQuery("call procedureX()");

System.out.println(new String(rs.getString(1)) );
```

inside the procedure "procedureX" I have:

```
select '1' as consult;
```

the thing is  that I want to print in java in console the select in MySQL with the statement `rs.getString(1)` , but when I try this, it prints error.

How can I print the result that returns MySQL ?

Thank you.

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: the error is so long, but it begins with 
"java.sql.SQLException: Before start of result set"

Comment: you are missing `rs.next()`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java: ResultSet exception - before start of result set](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2120255/java-resultset-exception-before-start-of-result-set)

Comment: Yes that's the error, thank you so much abl

Comment: Some might wonder why there is a `new String()` in your `println`