# how do i change a database value to a normal String?

Tags: java, mysql, string, jdbc

I have stored a database value orgname in a result set. I get only one orgname and i stored it in a Result set.

```
 orgName = result.getString("orgname");
```

I tried to retrieve the value using this getString function of result set. But the output I am receiving orgname as com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4ResultSet@333ce5bb. how can I get the actual name of the organization.

Comment: Please provide some actual information about the problem. [ask]

Comment: I couldn't share the actual data. It is confidential. the query i have used : select orgname from organnames where orgid=23; The result of this query, i have stored in result set and then used resultset.getString("orgname");. The value of the output is in database terms like i mentioned above.

Comment: You don't have to share the data. However, there is no schema information, there is no code. I am guessing you are using a programming language to process the result from the database? What `RDBMS` are you using?

Comment: I use Mysql. I am able to receive the data in the orgname variable but that value is like this com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4ResultSet@333ce5bb. That's the problem.

Comment: If you share additional information that belongs into the question **[Edit]** your question - do **not** post code in comments. You need to show the **complete** Java code that processes the result

Comment: A bit more code than just the line which gives you incorrect values would be very useful. What is in the database for `orgid=23`?

Comment: It seems you're printing the resultset, not the string you got out of the resultset. But of course, you still share no code, so we can't help. Voting to close.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Have a look at this: [Getting Data From Resultset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2120255/resultset-exception-before-start-of-result-set)

It isn't the same as your issue, but in general, the answers for that question cover how to do it properly. My guess (and guessing is all I can do without proper information) is that you have missed a call to position the result cursor... something like:

```
result.first();
```

Comment: Thank you! your guess is correct. I face the same problem. will get back to you

Comment: `result.first()` can throw an exception on type forward only result sets (one should use `next()` normally, and it isn't an answer to this question, because if the result set was still positioned before the first row, this would have thrown an `SQLException`.

Comment: My Eclipse suggested that SQLException and surrounded it with that exception loop prior to asking this question. I hope Peter's answer would resolve this.

Comment: @manikantanvsr - please add the new information / error / code / et.c. to your question.

Comment: You should refrain from answering badly phrased questions without sufficient information. You shouldn't try to just guess an answer, because your guess in this case is incorrect (or it would hint at a severe bug in the driver used by the OP, which is hard to believe).

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Yes, I get your point. I think I will leave this one alone, since the OP refuses to add more info, and his follow-up comments are plain confusing.

Comment: @PeterAbolins what you said worked for me. Thank you :)