# Getting an error "before start of result set" from mysql java

Tags: java, mysql

Hi I get an error message in the following code:

```
public Component createComponents(){
    Panel pane = new Panel();
    try{
        Connection myConn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/tondb?useSSL=false&useUnicode=true&useJDBCCompliantTimezoneShift=true&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=UTC","root","");
        Statement myStmt = myConn.createStatement();
        ResultSet myRs = myStmt.executeQuery("select * from activeemployees");
        ResultSet myRs2 = null;
        while (myRs.next()) {
            myRs2 = myStmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM employee WHERE ID="+myRs.getString("IDnumber"));
            pane.add(new Label(myRs2.getString("firstName")+","+myRs.getString("lastName"),20,20));
        }
    }catch(Exception e){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e.getMessage());
    }
    return pane;
}
```

Here's the image attached:

[image]

Can not figure out why.

Comment: What does the error actually say, is it an Exception (if so, can we see the stacktrace please)

Comment: You need a second Statement (and Connection) instance. Your second query closes the cursor on the first.

Comment: Possible dublicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2120255/resultset-exception-before-start-of-result-set

Comment: I can not find the solution to the problem at [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2120255/resultset-exception-before-start-of-result-set)

Comment: What part of _"You need to move the cursor to the first row."_ and an example that shows you need to call `next()` on the result set is unclear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you use `INNER JOIN` in your query to make it simpler? I guess you don't need two separate sql statement and execute them separately. In stead you can use join query to merge the data from two tables `employee` and `activeemployees` and fetch data from there. It will be much faster, too.

You may try this new query in your resultset:

```
ResultSet myRs = myStmt.executeQuery("SELECT E.firstName AS firstName, E.lastName AS lastName FROM employee E INNER JOIN activeemployees A ON E.IDnumber = A.IDnumber");
```

And then, new `ResultSet`, `myRs2` is not needed anymore. And you can use following code:

```
while (myRs.next()) {
    pane.add(new Label(myRs.getString("firstName")+","+myRs.getString("lastName"),20,20));
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, you are awesome!

Answer (score 1):

You can't execute several queries on one statement because if you do you reset the previous result set. So in your example, when the query for myRs2 is first executed myRs is cleared. Create a separate statement object inside the loop.

See the doc for [Statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#executeQuery(java.lang.String))