# Increasing an ID_Column value by 1 with mysql

Tags: java, mysql, sql

I wrote this code which increases a jlabel content by 1.
this works perfectly with SQLite database. but when I switched to MySQL, the same syntax produces no value at all. please what seems to be the problem. the code is as follows:

```
try{
    String sql = "Select max(ID) from ad_form";
    pst=con.prepareStatement(sql);
    rs=pst.executeQuery();
    String one =rs.getString("max(ID)");
    id.setText(one);

    int all = Integer.valueOf(id.getText());
    all=all+1;
    id.setText(String.valueOf(all));
    }catch(SQLException | NumberFormatException e ){
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,e);
    }
    finally{
                try{
                    rs.close();
                    pst.close();
                }
                catch(Exception ep){
                    ep.getMessage();
                }

            }
```

anytime the code runs, the jlabel which is to display the value is blank.

Comment: That's still valid SQL syntax in MySQL. Have you checked if there's an error? It's plausible the `max(ID)` column is coming back with a different name (e.g., `MAX(ID)`), in which case `SELECT MAX(ID) AS fake_column_name FROM ad_form` would still work.

Comment: the error message is : Before start of result set @VoteyDisciple

Comment: That error suggests: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2120255/resultset-exception-before-start-of-result-set

Comment: thanks very much @VoteyDisciple. the rs.next() was the missing link. most grateful bro.

Comment: This looks like a bad idea. What happens if two connections execute the same piece of code at the same time?

Comment: well for now the frame handling the new insertions is only meant for one connection. but in future, wont keep practising that @Strawberry. thanks bro

Answer (score 0):

The issue is the naming of the unnamed expression.  This is going to vary by database.  So simply do:

```
Select max(ID) as max_id from ad_form
```

and then:

```
String one =rs.getString("max_id");
```

This will work in any database.

I am concerned about fetching the maximum id.  If your desire is to increment it by one and use it for a subsequent insert, then this is the wrong approach.  Instead, you should be using an `auto_increment` column.

Comment: I tried your answer @Gordon. but still didn't work. I want each member to have a unique set of int values as id. that's why I used this approach

Comment: @RodneyNart . . . You should probably be using an `auto_increment` column.  This should be done in the database, automatically, when a row is inserted, not in the application.

Comment: thank you bro. will heed to your advice. most grateful